# Storing Special Characters titles in update_post_meta in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, csv

I have created the custom plug-in to store the user information via CSV import. For that i have created the custom post types along with custom fields. But everything stored in my database, except special characters in user name like **'Évana '**. How to overcome this problem.

**`update_post_meta($post_id,'username_name', $line_of_text[1]);`**

Note: I have read all the values from CSV and converted into array. Here `$line_of_text[1]` holds the values of user name.

Comment: What's you database default charset? Try using UTF-8 on your tables. Why are you updating post meta with user-related meta?

Comment: @anatoli my database character set is define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'); and define('DB_COLLATE', '');

Comment: That may not reflect your current database status. Check the DB from your phpMyAdmin...

Comment: @anatoli i more doubt is that, if i assigned the value directly means, the user name is stored , like **bold** update_post_meta($post_id,'username_name', 'Évana ');

Answer (score 1):

I stored the special characters values in my post title using the htmlentities() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php